# Fixed position issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

My layout is 3 column layout. Left side is pinned to left. Right is pinned to right. Middle section is only scrollable.

For Left side I used following css:

```
.left {
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    float:left
}
```

For Right side I used following css:

```
.right {
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    float:right
}
```

Both columns have large content. If i used `position:fixed;`, I can not view the full content. I am totally confused.

I need Left and right Pinned to left and right side. I want to view my full content also. Is it possible???

http://jsfiddle.net/SM5e9/

Comment: use `position:absolute;` I think this will help... :D

Comment: Use Width:auto; for all 3 classes .left, .right, middle

Comment: so...Did anything work? If so, please accept (and possibly upvote) the best answer.

Comment: If using `position:fixed` then you don't need `float`.

Answer (score 1):

`position: fixed` is meant to keep the element attached to the viewport when scrolling. Read more about `position` values [here on w3.org/wiki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/position#Values).

From the wiki:

> **Fixed** - According to the 'absolute' model, the box is taken out of the normal flow but does not move when scrolled. The box's position is specified with the 'top', 'right', 'bottom', and 'left' properties.

---

That said, I assume you want a three column layout. One easy way is using `display: table`.

In this example:

1. All elements are set to `height: 100%` in order to adjust to your content, regardless of quantity.
2. `.wrap` contains the columns with `display:table` and then aligns them with `display: table-cell;`

[Have a jsBin Example!](http://jsbin.com/teham/4/edit)

[Here is the wiki page](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/display) for the `display` property on w3.org.

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body {  
    height: 100%;
}
.wrap, .left, .right, .content {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.wrap {
    background: #999;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
}
.left {
    width: 50px;
    background: #F00;
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    width: 100px;
    background: #FF0;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think to view the full content is to decrease the size of the content. ( In your example the font-size ). Or don't use fixed positioning. Instead use absolute positioning. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no prob with Position:fixed. Since the content has been added with break tags, it goes down beyond the viewport . So Add overflow:scroll to the page or parent element. This will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `.middle` and remove `float:left` from `.middle`:

```
margin-left:50%; margin-right: 50%;position:absolute;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/litari/SM5e9/1/)